# Safari: jQuery toggle() issue with svg

Tags: jquery, svg, safari, toggle, transform

I have a document with svg paths and I'm flipping them horizontally using css classes with `transform: scaleX(-1)`. This works well in Chrome but not on Safari.

```js
$('#bt1').click(function() {
  $('#rectOut').toggleClass('red blue');
})

$('#bt2').click(function() {
  $('#svgPath path').toggleClass('silver hotpink');
})
```

```css
#rectOut {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#rectIn {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
button {
  margin: 20px 0 40px;
}
svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
}
path {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
.silver {
  fill: silver;
}
.hotpink {
  fill: hotpink;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rectOut" class="rect red">
  <div id="rectIn"><p>123</p></div>
</div>
<button id="bt1">toggle rectangle</button>

<div>
  <svg id="svgPath">
    <path x="0" y="0" class="silver" d="M 0 0 C 50 0, 70 50, 150 50 C 0 100, 0 50, 0 0 Z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
<button id="bt2">toggle shape</button>
```

I have a div and an svg for comparison. Both the div and the svg have a css class that defines their color fill. I created buttons that use jQuery's toggle() to switch between those classes and other classes with different colors, and with `transform: scaleX(-1)`. This works fine for the div on both browsers, but on Safari the svg stays flipped even when the class with the transform is no longer applied.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

No default is set, so `transform: scaleX(-1)` remains.

## Solution

Set `#rectOut` and `#svgPath path` to `transform: scaleX(1)` so that there’s a default for Safari to fall back to

Comment: Thank you @pygeek, setting a default worked. It should be `transform: scaleX(1)` however. Using `transform: scaleX(0)` will make the width zero. Could you edit your answer, so I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: @maguskrool Updated. Apologies for the typo.